# Property of projective modules over k[G].

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $E,F$ be two $k[G]$-modules, where $k[G]$ is the group algebra with $G$ finite, and $E$ is projective, show that
> $$ \dim Hom^{G}(E,F)=\dim Hom^G(F,E).$$

Is this a well-known result? I have no idea to prove this, any help?

Comment: Are you interested in the general case? Or can we assume that $\operatorname{char} k$ does not divide $|G|$?

Comment: Oh, yes, maybe we need this assumption. And I want to know about the general case, thanks a lot!